# Display table: header-cells width is not equal to body-cells width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to divide a table in two parts but i would like to keep the display:table-cell width for the header.
here my code snipe:

```
 <div class="table" style="margin-bottom:0">

    <div class="row header">
      <div class="cell sorting sort" data-sort="name">Name</div>
      <div class="cell sorting sort" data-sort="age">Age</div>
      <div class="cell sorting sorting_desc">Occupation</div>
      <div class="cell">Location</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="table list">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell name" data-title="Name">Luke Peters</div>
      <div class="cell age" data-title="Age">25</div>
      <div class="cell" data-title="Occupation">Freelance Web Developer</div>
      <div class="cell" data-title="Location">Brookline, MA</div>
    </div>
...
```

For the script I need a place to put the data in. Here it is the div.list
But it destroy my header-layout, it has a different width then. Is there a way to have the width of the header-cells equal to list-cells?

Here ist a codepen: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Hamburger123456/pen/GRWjzBJ)

Comment: If you're creating a table, why not just use a table? It's semantically correct and will solve your problem.

Comment: @ psdpainter: my table is a responsive table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using two separate tables. You can put the second table into the first table and set `.list` to `display: contents` for desktop view.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background: #2b2b2b;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.table {
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: table;
}

.table.list {
  display: contents;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .table {
    display: block;
  }
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.row:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

.row.header {
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ea6153;
}

.row.green {
  background: #27ae60;
}

.row.blue {
  background: #2980b9;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .row {
    padding: 14px 0 7px;
    display: block;
  }
  .row.header {
    padding: 0;
    height: 6px;
  }
  .row.header .cell {
    display: none;
  }
  .row .cell {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .row .cell:before {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    content: attr(data-title);
    min-width: 98px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #969696;
    display: block;
  }
}

.cell {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .cell {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    display: block;
  }
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id=test>

    <div class="table" style="margin-bottom:0">

      <div class="row header">
        <div class="cell sorting sort" data-sort="name">
          Name
        </div>
        <div class="cell sorting sort" data-sort="age">
          Age
        </div>
        <div class="cell sorting sorting_desc">
          Occupation
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
          Location
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="table list">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell name" data-title="Name">
            Luke Peters
          </div>
          <div class="cell age" data-title="Age">
            25
          </div>
          <div class="cell" data-title="Occupation">
            Freelance Web Developer
          </div>
          <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
            Brookline, MA
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell name" data-title="Name">
            Joseph Smith
          </div>
          <div class="cell age" data-title="Age">
            27
          </div>
          <div class="cell" data-title="Occupation">
            Project Manager
          </div>
          <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
            Somerville, MA
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell name" data-title="Name">
            Maxwell Johnson
          </div>
          <div class="cell age" data-title="Age">
            26
          </div>
          <div class="cell" data-title="Occupation">
            UX Architect & Designer
          </div>
          <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
            Arlington, MA
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell name" data-title="Name">
            Harry Harrison
          </div>
          <div class="cell age" data-title="Age">
            25
          </div>
          <div class="cell" data-title="Occupation">
            Front-End Developer
          </div>
          <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
            Boston, MA
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
  <!-- !test -->

</div>
```

Comment: that where i started with. But here I need one more wrapper for my list. (div.list)

Comment: sorry do not work. Headers are expanded now but the list part has no width

Comment: _the list part has no width_ I don't understand what you mean. Isn't look like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGGlh.png

Comment: OH, sorry you also changed the html. It works!! Thx